# Comparing column data in 2 table rows

Tags: jquery, datatables

I need to compare information within a jQuery DataTable, on `initComplete`.

As you can see from the HTML below, each `tr` has a `data-attribute` of `data-application-id`. For each Application Id, there are 2 table rows.

```
<table id="reportDataTable" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr data-application-id="1">
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Joe</td>
            <td>Bloggs</td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-application-id="1">
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Jane</td>
            <td>Bloggs</td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-application-id="2">
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Joe</td>
            <td>Bloggs</td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-application-id="2">
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Joe</td>
            <td>Bloggs</td>
        </tr>   
        <tr data-application-id="3">
            <td>3</td>
            <td>Joe</td>
            <td>Floggs</td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-application-id="3">
            <td>3</td>
            <td>Joe</td>
            <td>Bloggs</td>
        </tr>       
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This code below loops through all table rows within the DataTable and logs the `data-application-id`.

```
$('#reportDataTable').DataTable({
    initComplete: function () {
        $('tbody tr').each(function () {
            console.log($(this).data("application-id"));
        });
    }
});
```

I'm at a loss on how to compare the columns and add a class or style to different values. The loop needs to compare each column with the corresponding column within the same `data-application-id` and highlight both columns if there is a difference.

*There could be several columns, not just Id, First Name and Last Name*

[image: Image on how the table should look.]

Thanks in advance

Comment: In theory you can sort `$('tbody tr')` and then use two pointers: one index for first column with application-id value, second for next value with the same application-id. When you have a new second index iterate it backward till it is not equal first one, compare values in the table. If a value is not the same then mark a cell. 

Hope you get an idea.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

```js
$('#reportDataTable').DataTable({
    initComplete: function () {
  var p=0;
    var applicationIdArray = [];
        $('tbody tr').each(function (i,v) {
            applicationIdArray.push($(this).data("application-id"));
        });
       //make it unique
       var uniqueIds = $.unique(applicationIdArray);
       $.each(uniqueIds,function(i,v){
         var elements = $('tr[data-application-id="'+v+'"]');
          var tdArray = [];
    var eachTdArray = [];
          $.each(elements,function(x,y){
           var eachTd = $(y).find('td');
            tdArray.push(eachTd);
   
          });
    $.each(tdArray,function(b,n){
    $.each(n,function(zz,xx){
     eachTdArray.push($(xx).text());
    });
    eachTdArray.push('br');
   });
    var cc = eachTdArray.indexOf("br");
    cc++;
     for(var mm=0;mm<cc;mm++){
      if(eachTdArray[mm]==eachTdArray[mm+cc]){
      
      }
      else{
       $('tbody tr:eq('+p+')').find('td:eq('+mm+')').css({'background-color':'red'});
       $('tbody tr:eq('+(p+1)+')').find('td:eq('+mm+')').css({'background-color':'red'});
      }
     }
    p=p+2;
       });
    }
});
```

```html
<table id="reportDataTable" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr data-application-id="1">
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Joe</td>
            <td>Bloggs</td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-application-id="1">
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Jane</td>
            <td>Bloggs</td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-application-id="2">
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Joe</td>
            <td>Bloggs</td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-application-id="2">
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Joe</td>
            <td>Bloggs</td>
        </tr>   
        <tr data-application-id="3">
            <td>3</td>
            <td>Joe</td>
            <td>Floggs</td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-application-id="3">
            <td>3</td>
            <td>Joe</td>
            <td>Bloggs</td>
        </tr>       
    </tbody>
</table>

<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-pasqAKBDmFT4eHoN2ndd6lN370kFiGUFyTiUHWhU7k8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src = "https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to add a code-only CSS class attribute to the cols you want to check - see html below. This gives you an immediate means of addressing the columns - kind of like using a data attribute, but using class selectors is uber faster and on a big data set that may be important.

Then you need to get and iterate the col values noting the immediate previous value in each case - when you detect a difference you mark all the matching classes in the group as different. And you need to know when you are in the first pass within a group & column combo.

I used the 'cols' array to give the selectors of the columns being inspected - this is clearly extendable as per your point about there being more columns in the real use-case.

Run the snippet in full-screen mode otherwise the console obscures the table.

```js
var groups = [],
  pass = 1,
  prev,
  rows = 0,
  cols = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']; // Handy css class markers of cols we wish to examine, results,    
/*
Prepare a list of rows with 2+ entries matching on data-application-id
*/
$('tbody tr').each(function() {
  var idx = parseInt($(this).data("application-id"), 10);

  // if the slot has a value add one, or set to 1 if first hit
  groups[idx] = (groups[idx] ? groups[idx] + 1 : 1);

});

/*
Walk through the identified TR groups and look for differences. If we find a 
difference we use the classes that we added for convenience to apply some UX.
*/

for (var i = 0, max = groups.length; i < max; i = i + 1) {

  if (groups[i] && groups[i] > 1) { // could be a gappy array, and we only process items with 2+ entries

    console.log('Process group ' + i + ' count of elements =' + groups[i])

    prev = ['-x-', '-x-', '-x-']; // Used to note previous col values in same-row groups. One entry per slot in cols array, initial values all set to an unlikely value. Must happen here as reset oer group-col pass.

    pass = 1 // reset first pass flag - needed so we know not to be choosey on first pass when data always changes

    $('tbody tr[data-application-id="' + i + '"]').each(function() {
      rows = rows + 1;

      for (var c = 0, maxC = cols.length; c < maxC; c = c + 1) {

        var thisVal = $(this).find('.' + cols[c]).html();

        console.log('Check col slot ' + c + ' matching class ' + cols[c] + ' with val=' + thisVal + ' vs prev=' + prev[c])

        if (pass !== 1 && thisVal !== prev[c]) {

          console.log('Difference detected !')

          // found a difference, mark it difference
          $('tbody tr[data-application-id="' + i + '"]').find('.' + cols[c]).css({
            backgroundColor: 'cyan'
          })
        }
        prev[c] = thisVal; // note this value for next pass
      }

      pass = pass + 1;

    })
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="reportDataTable" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr data-application-id="1">
      <td class='col1'>1</td>
      <td class='col2'>Joe</td>
      <td class='col3'>Bloggs</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-application-id="1">
      <td class='col1'>1</td>
      <td class='col2'>Jane</td>
      <td class='col3'>Bloggs</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-application-id="2">
      <td class='col1'>2</td>
      <td class='col2'>Joe</td>
      <td class='col3'>Bloggs</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-application-id="2">
      <td class='col1'>2</td>
      <td class='col2'>Joe</td>
      <td class='col3'>Bloggs</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-application-id="3">
      <td class='col1'>3</td>
      <td class='col2'>Joe</td>
      <td class='col3'>Floggs</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-application-id="3">
      <td class='col1'>3</td>
      <td class='col2'>Joe</td>
      <td class='col3'>Bloggs</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-application-id="1">
      <td class='col1'>1</td>
      <td class='col2'>Joel</td>
      <td class='col3'>Bloggs</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-application-id="3">
      <td class='col1'>3</td>
      <td class='col2'>Joe</td>
      <td class='col3'>Bloges</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```